# How to free the memory allocated by cdev_alloc?

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

The "LDD3, Chapter 3" show us that we can allocate a `struct cdev` structure at runtime like this :

```
struct cdev *cdev_ptr = cdev_alloc();
```

But I don't know how to free this memory, because `cdev_del()` seems not to free this memory allocated by `kzmalloc()` in `cdev_alloc()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling for `cdev_del()` will free `cdev` structure, created by `cdev_alloc()`, *automatically*.

According to [implementation](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/char_dev.c#L520), `cdev_alloc()` registers special callback for internal kobject. This callback is called when reference count of the object is dropped to zero and it frees allocated memory.

Also, [description for cdev_del](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/char_dev.c#L474) says:

> /** 
>       * cdev_del() - remove a cdev from the system
>       * @p: the cdev structure to be removed
>       *
>       * cdev_del() removes @p from the system, **possibly freeing the structure**
>       * **itself.**
>       */